# SQL SUM OF VARIABLES

Tags: mysql, sql

Regarding the query1, how can i get the sum of all columns variables (VAR_ACTIVIDADE, VAR1, VAR2, VAR3, VAR4) ?

In the image the result that i intend . [IMG1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjJUk.jpg)

query1 ->

```
SELECT ACTIVIDADE AS VAR_ACTIVIDADE, 
       COUNT(*) AS VAR_SUM, 
       SUM(TAT_DATAREGISTO <= 1) VAR1, 
       SUM(TAT_DATAREGISTO >= 2 AND TAT_DATAREGISTO <= 3) VAR2, 
       SUM(TAT_DATAREGISTO >= 4 AND TAT_DATAREGISTO <= 9) VAR3, 
       SUM(TAT_DATAREGISTO >= 10) VAR4 
FROM MAIN_TAB
WHERE ESTADO_REP IN ('NULL', 'AGUARDA PEÇAS')
  AND EXCLUIR_YN <> 'YES_DEL'
GROUP BY ACTIVIDADE
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Use [WITH ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) in GROUP BY. It should be what you want.

Comment: @IvoRubim Please accept the answers. Anyway, there will be a problem when you want to obtain total sum of many groups. It's a pity, that there is no GROUPING SETS (or there is but I haven't noticed it) clause like e.g. in SQL SERVER.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(VAR_ACTIVIDADE) VAR_ACTIVIDADE,
SUM(VAR1) VAR1,
SUM(VAR2) VAR2,
SUM(VAR3) VAR3 ,
SUM(VAR4) VAR4 
from
(
SELECT ACTIVIDADE AS VAR_ACTIVIDADE, 
COUNT(*) AS VAR_SUM, 
SUM(TAT_DATAREGISTO <= 1) VAR1, 
SUM(TAT_DATAREGISTO >= 2 AND TAT_DATAREGISTO <= 3) VAR2, 
SUM(TAT_DATAREGISTO >= 4 AND TAT_DATAREGISTO <= 9) VAR3, 
SUM(TAT_DATAREGISTO >= 10) VAR4 
FROM MAIN_TAB WHERE ESTADO_REP IN('NULL','AGUARDA PEÇAS') AND EXCLUIR_YN <> 'YES_DEL' GROUP BY ACTIVIDADE
)Z
```

Try above query.

Comment: Doesn't work like i want . Just shows de sum of all columns , and i need display all discriminated values and sums (rows + columns) . TY

Answer (score 0):

Use case?

```
SELECT ACTIVIDADE AS VAR_ACTIVIDADE, 
COUNT(*) AS VAR_SUM, 
sum(when TAT_DATAREGISTO <= 1 then 1 else 0 end) VAR1, 
SUM(when TAT_DATAREGISTO between 2 and 3 then 1 else 0 end) VAR2, 
SUM(when TAT_DATAREGISTO between 4 and 9 then 1 else 0 end) VAR3, 
SUM(when TAT_DATAREGISTO >= 10 then 1 else 0 end) VAR4 
FROM MAIN_TAB 
WHERE ESTADO_REP IN('NULL','AGUARDA PEÇAS') 
AND EXCLUIR_YN <> 'YES_DEL' 
GROUP BY ACTIVIDADE
```

This will count the values for each criteria in the appropriate columns (ie, sum of 1's)

Comment: "Regarding the query1, how can i get the sum of all columns variables (VAR_ACTIVIDADE, VAR1, VAR2, VAR3, VAR4) ?"